# Iterate over values in pandas column containing lists and retrieve only unique values

Tags: python, regex, pandas

This is three questions that i just cant figure out, hope someone can help me out.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Col1': ['ONE, ONE, NULL', 'ONE, TWO, THREE', 'TWO, NULL, TEN']}
index = pd.Index(['d1','d2','d3'])
data = pd.DataFrame(data,index=index)
pattern = 'ONE|TWO'                 <----QUESTION1
data['Col1'].str.findall(pattern)   <----QUESTION2
```

**Question1:** How can i change this regex so that 'ONE' is only found once in d1? As it is now each instance of ONE found will be returned as shown below.

```
d1    [ONE, ONE]
d2    [ONE, TWO]
d3         [TWO]
```

i want this

```
d1         [ONE]
d2    [ONE, TWO]
d3         [TWO]
```

**Question2:**
I want to take list d1, d2 and d3 and make into one list containing only unique values. That is something like this:

```
set(d1 + d2 + d3) ---> ['ONE', 'TWO']
```

**Question3:**
If i would have done something like this:

```
data['Col2'] = data['Col1'].str.findall(pattern)
```

How could i iterate over every row in Col2 to get the same results as i asked for in Question2?

Answer (score 3):

You can use reduce (over set.union):

```
In [11]: reduce(set.union, data['Col1'].str.findall(pattern), set())
Out[11]: {'ONE', 'TWO'}
```

Another option is to use a list comprehension:

```
In [12]: [w for w in ['ONE', 'TWO'] if data['Col1'].str.contains(w).any()]
Out[12]: ['ONE', 'TWO']
```

Comment: Solves Question2 perfectly, thanks! How would i go on and extract a list from a pandas table? I would like to create a new list for every row in Col2, the list created should have the shape as seen in Col2.

Comment: @user3139545 I'm not sure what you're asking for :s FWIW The rule of thumb in pandas is to avoid lists in a DataFrame / Series, usually there's a better way.

Comment: In Col2 i will have a string looking like this ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'] now i want to read this string for every row and make it in to a python list.

Comment: I have not found a better way, the lists in the dataframe contains IDs to instances in another frame that are related to the line in this frame.

Comment: The goal is to make an index object from all the lists in Col2 to only select the relevant IDs from another dataframe.

Comment: Is the issue that result of [11] is set not a list (just apply set to it). Atm this feels like the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/184179)...

Comment: Perhaps `data['Col1'].str.split(', ').apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)` might be more useful output... I'm still not sure I see what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

For **Question 1** try this: `data['Col1'].str.findall(pattern).apply(set)`

For **Question 2,3** try this: `{x for s in data['Col1'].str.findall(pattern).apply(set) for x in s}`

Comment: This stores the values with the set() text left. So for d1, Col2 would say set([ONE]), can i not do this and just get [ONE] as a result?

Comment: For question3 i do not want to use Col1, i want to create lists as they are shown in Col2.